# QFileDialog Slow Network

Tags: c++, qt

I am using `QFileDialog` both `getOpenFileName` and `getSaveFileName`.  I have a file out on the network (slow connection), that I load with `getOpenFileName`.  Then if I try to create a new `QFileDialog`, it takes forever to load.

I looked at the process with Process Monitor and I can see it slowly crawling through every file in the network location where I last opened the file.  It remains slow until I restart the computer.  What can I do to speed this up?

Here is some code:

**Open File Dialog**

```
QString filename;
QFileDialog fd(this);
filename = fd.getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open CSV File"), ".",tr("CSV Files (*.csv)"));
```

**Save File Dialog**

```
QString filename;
QFileDialog fd(this);
filename = fd.getSaveFileName(this,tr("Save CSV File"), ".",tr("CSV Files (*.csv)"));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's nothing else that you can do about that if you use the native dialog like you do. The `getOpenFileName` opens the native file dialog, and it's this native platform code that enumerates the files in the target directory.

If you don't need the native dialog, you can do all sorts of things to work around the blocking/synchronous directory iteration interface to fundamentally asynchronous I/O resources.

Comment: To be pedantic, you *can* do something about it. You can re-implement the functionality yourself and handle slow network responses differently (for example by showing an error - obviously you can't get the actual results any faster).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, and unfortunately most filesystem access is synchronous because the internals of the OS are often broken and completely hide the asynchronicity of the real world. So e.g. often you can read chunks from a large file asynchronously, but reading directory contents will block even if you try to execute it as an overlapped/async operation. The best you could do is toss it all into a worker thread and show your own dialog, and stop the thread when the OS call returns. It's wasteful and sad. Native dialogs could be async... but aren't since VFS dir iteration isn't :(

Comment: So, as I said... ;)

Comment: My one issue with this is that I can navigate to and open the CSV file in a matter of 10-15 seconds with Explorer and Excel, but the QFileDialog takes over 10 minutes just to popup the second time I run it.

Comment: @dlams Then you have to debug your Qt build, figure out why it breaks, and file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Try the option `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog`. This should forbid to open a native dialog.

I am using non-native dialogs (by deriving from QFileDialog) for years to get rid of the problems you described.

Comment: Looks like this is a common problem for people, but doesn't happen to be helping here. I'm guessing bug at this point.